# Select Limited rows and columns from Database table

Tags: database

I have 10 columns and 1000 rows in a table. i want to select 2 cols ans 50 rows only? Can any one help me...?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What database are you using? SQL Server? Oracle? MySql?

Comment: Then Oded's answer will work for you. I still recommend reading up about SQL though to get some basic knowledge if you need to work with a database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 50 
col1, col2
FROM myTable
```

Answer (score 2):

I would advise starting at a beginners course in SQL.  http://www.w3schools.com/sql/

W3Schools has some good interactive tutorials for beginners.

Comment: @Oded, nice find, yes I have found some factual errors with W3Schools but when it comes to a complete beginner I notice that it seems to dumb things down to the basest level making it easier for some people to understand.  I would only recommend it for the most beginner level people who need to get basic knowledge as quick as possible.

Comment: True, but the question was asked by a beginner and the answer is aimed at that person. People who already know about SQL will most likely be more adept at using Google to find what they need since they'll know exactly what to look for, a complete beginner won't.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're completely new to databases, you should try learning about SQL (Structured Query Language) - the SELECT statement is a good place to start... http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT col_name1, col_name2 FROM tablename ORDER BY col_name_you_want_to_order_by DESC LIMIT 5
```

This is will select the top 5 rows based on your choices.

You can have multiple col_names specified there and you can change the number 5 at the end to get your desired number of results.

Comment: That will work in MySql, it won't work in SQL Server, not sure about Oracle or any other DBs. It would be more helpful if we knew what kind of database they were using!

Comment: @Tabby: Exactly he has not mentioned what server and I have made an assumption based on MySQL's popularity with newbies.